# how to test the loading of the main page?

Tags: python, django

please help fix the test. 
tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client
import os
from django.conf import settings


class HomePageTest(TestCase):

    def test_homepage_available(self):
        c = Client()
        response = c.get('/')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
#from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'mutants.views.inner_page', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

as a result of testing in the console displays the following error message:

```
c:\Python33\django_projects\mutants>python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'... E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_homepage_available (accounts.tests.HomePageTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Python33\django_projects\mutants\accounts\tests.py", line 11, in test_homepage_available
    response = c.get('/')   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 473, in get
    response = super(Client, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)
   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 280, in get
    return self.request(**r)
   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 444, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 536, in reraise
    raise value
   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
   File "c:\Python33\django_projects\mutants\mutants\views.py", line 13, in inner_page
    obj = Page.get_main_page()
   File "c:\Python33\django_projects\mutants\mutants\models.py", line 39, in get_main_page
    return self.objects.filter(main_page=True)[0]
   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 132, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0] IndexError: list index out of range

----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Ran 1 test in 0.030s

FAILED (errors=1) Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

c:\Python33\django_projects\mutants>
```

Comment: The error thrown is pretty clear: `IndexError`. Somewhere in your `models.py` you want to retrieve the first element of a queryset which is empty. This is all I can say without the actual code of your models file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each test starts from a blank database. If you don't create any data in your tests themselves, eg in the setUp method or via fixtures, then your views that are being tested won't find any data. In this case, your `get_main_page` method is expecting at least one entry in the `Page` model, and you don't have any.

Of course, this is actually exposing a bug in your code itself: it crashes when there is no data. If this is a use case you need to handle, then you should probably check for that situation and display a proper error page.